# Using reference variable passed to the constructor in other functions c#

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a user control which displays another user control when a menu item is clicked. I have passed a reference of a collection that is to be used in UserControl2

```
private void Menu_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Window window = new Window
        {
            Title = "UserControl2",
            Content = new ColumnDataControl(ref collectionOfData)
        };
        window.ShowDialog();

    }
```

I use the collection in the constructor UserControl2 to initialize some variables.
The UserControl2 has a button which when clicked should change collectionOfData (reference passed to the constructor). How do I achieve this?

My constructor -

```
public ColumnDataControl(ref ObservableCollection<data> collection)
    {
        this.collectionOfData = collection;
    }

private button_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     //How do I access the reference here so that the change is reflected in UserControl1??
}
```

Comment: change the data in the collection that was passed as a reference from the other user control.

Comment: make a field in the **UserControl2** set it from ``CoulmnDataControl()`` and then use it in ``button_click`` event

Comment: you want the updated collection in **UserControl1** ?

Comment: Yes exactly! I want the updated collection in UserControl1.

Comment: So in the current way where are you facing problem it is not reflecting changes on **UserControl1**?

Comment: I cannot access the reference outside the constructor in order to change it. My problem is not with reflecting changes. My problem is with how to make the changes since the reference is not available outside the constructor.

Comment: can't you do in event ``this.collectionOfData`` like you doing in contructor?

Comment: Can you store your collection in geter seter and retrieve back any your usercontrol

Comment: why not declare the observablecollection outside of the scope and set it in the cope and access it in the button?

Comment: I can set it to public static in UserControl1 and access it in UserControl2. But static variables call the constructor twice and this causes problems in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that passing the collection as `ref` is what you really nead. This approach is probably what you're looking for because I guess you want to modify the collection and not to replace it because it would break your databinding if any (and I'm pretty sure you have it databound):

**1st control**: in the 1st control pass the collection to a property that you add to the 2nd control:

```
private void Menu_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Window window = new Window
    {
        Title = "UserControl2",
        Content = new ColumnDataControl() 
        {
            CollectionOfData = collectionOfData
        };
    };
    window.ShowDialog();

}
```

**2nd control**: create a property to hold the collection:

```
public ColumnDataControl() { }

ObservableCollection<data> CollectionOfData { get; set; }

private button_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CollectionOfData.Add(...);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have the collection in the context, you could simply refer to it by using the name,

```
collectionOfData.Where(..........)
```

**EDIT:**

(i)If you want to change the initial data in the 2nd user control and want that to be reflected in 1st user control, you need to implement [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for your collection.

(ii)Another way is modify the collection in the user control and send it back to the parent user control.

Comment: I have the reference only in the constructor. I copy that reference data to a local variable in my constructor. I want to change the refernced data in the other function.

Comment: My question was how do I change the initial data in the second user  control? The initial data is passed only to the constructor. I can send it back to the parent control but was wondering if there was nay straightforward approach.